# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una imagen que está guardado en mi Base de Datos Mysql en mi Api de Google Maps?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un proyecto en Android, donde me guarde los registros y la foto de una persona en mi base de datos Mysql y se muestre en una página web cuando presione en el marcador de la api de google maps; a parte de que la foto se guarde en mi base de datos, también hago que se guarde en una carpeta llamada "FOTOS". Hasta el momento he podido mostrar todo, menos la foto. Este es el código:

**Parte donde tengo las funciones**

```
<script>
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-2.16667, -79.9),
          zoom: 13
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('resultado.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
             // var apellido = markerElem.getAttribute('apellido');              
              var foto = markerElem.getAttribute('foto');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              //var strongs = document.createElement('strongs');
              strong.textContent = name
              //strongs.textContent = apellido
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              //infowincontent.appendChild(strongs);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = foto
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}

    </script>
```

**Aquí es donde muestro los datos**

```
function parseToXML($htmlStr){
  $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
  return $xmlStr;
}
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$result_markers = "SELECT * FROM usuario INNER JOIN registro on usuario.cod_usuario = registro.cod_usuario";

$resultado_markers = mysqli_query($conexion, $result_markers);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node

echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row_markers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_markers)){
    // Add to XML document node

  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row_markers['nombres']) . '" ';
  //echo 'apellido="' . parseToXML($row_markers['apellidos']) . '" ';
  echo 'foto="' . parseToXML($row_markers['foto']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row_markers['latitud'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row_markers['longitud'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

**Tendría en mi proyecto algo como esto**
[image: Solo me muestra la ruta donde tengo guardada la foto]

**Si alguien me puede ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias***